Вывести детальное изображение раздела торгового каталога
Немного застрял на, довольно, простой задаче.
У раздела каталога есть превью и детальное изображение, хочу вывести его в шаблоне.
Пишу
<img src="<?=$arSection["DETAIL_PICTURE"]["SRC"]?>" alt="<?=$arSection["DETAIL_PICTURE"]["ALT"]?>"/>

Ничего не выводит 
Пробую (проверить, выводит ли вообще изображения)
<img src="<?=$arSection["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["SRC"]?>" alt="<?=$arSection["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["ALT"]?>"/>

Не работает 
И только, написав
<img src="<?=$arSection["PICTURE"]["SRC"]?>" alt="<?=$arSection["PICTURE"]["ALT"]?>"/>

Мне выводится превьюшнаое изображение
Подскажите как вывести детальное
Полный код шаблона - прилагается
<main class="wrapper">
    <section>
        <div class="flex column-flex content">
            <h4>КАТАЛОГ</h4>
            <?
            $CURRENT_DEPTH=$arResult["SECTION"]["DEPTH_LEVEL"]+1;
            foreach($arResult["SECTIONS"] as $arSection):
            
               if($CURRENT_DEPTH==$arSection["DEPTH_LEVEL"])
               {
               ?>
                <div class="flex row-flex catalog-first-box">
                    <div class="catalog-first-img"><img src="<?=$arSection["PICTURE"]["SRC"]?>" alt="<?=$arSection["PICTURE"]["ALT"]?>"/></div>
                    <div class="flex column-flex catalog-first-text">
                        <h2><?=$arSection["NAME"]?></h2>
                        <a href="<?=$arSection["SECTION_PAGE_URL"]?>" class="btn-gray">ПОДРОБНЕЕ</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
               <?
               }
            
            ?>
            <?endforeach?>
        </div>
    </section>
</main>



В параметре "SECTION_FIELDS" компонента необходимо указать, какие поля секции нужны для отображения.

"SECTION_FIELDS" => array(// Section Fields
                    0 => "CODE",
                    1 => "NAME",
                    2 => "PICTURE",
                    3 => "DETAIL_PICTURE",
                ),


Если поле "PICTURE" компонент подтягивает автоматически, то поле "DETAIL_PICTURE" в шаблоне нужно будет подтянуть самостоятельно

\Bitrix\Iblock\Component\Tools::getFieldImageData(
                $arSection,
                array('DETAIL_PICTURE'),
                \Bitrix\Iblock\Component\Tools::IPROPERTY_ENTITY_SECTION,
                'IPROPERTY_VALUES'
            );

После этого можно будет использовать $arSection["DETAIL_PICTURE"]["SRC"] и $arSection["DETAIL_PICTURE"]["ALT"].

не совсем понял, куда вставить вот эту часть, понял, что в шаблон, но куда именно, не совсем
\Bitrix\Iblock\Component\Tools::getFieldImageData(                 $arSection,                 array('DETAIL_PICTURE'),                 \Bitrix\Iblock\Component\Tools::IPROPERTY_ENTITY_SECTION,                 'IPROPERTY_VALUES'             );

После начала цикла foreach($arResult["SECTIONS"] as $arSection):
